# Hyperv does not appear to be installed

Tags: hyper-v, minikube

Hyper V has been started.

OS: Winsows 10 Pro
RAM: 4GB

*****Power shell is started in Admin mode********

I have created a Virtual Switch Manager then I am trying the below command.

`minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Minikube Switch"` it is throwing below error.

```
minikube v1.7.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18363 Build 18363
* Using the hyperv driver based on user configuration
! 'hyperv' driver reported an issue: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online failed:
* Suggestion: Start PowerShell as Administrator, and run: 'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All'
* Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/hyperv/
```

X hyperv does not appear to be installed

Comment: Have you tried the command suggested on the error ? `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All'`

Comment: Yes I have tried that but still I have the error when I am running minikube command

Comment: Did you tried to execute `minikube delete` before? Maybe this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1967) could help

Comment: Yes tried that as well

Answer (score 6):

I also experienced the same issue on my Windows 10 enterprise machine. Following below steps correctly probably solved my problem:

1. Start the Windows Powershell as administrator. Note starting with administrator privileges is essential.
2. Execute command

   Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
3. After successful execution, restart the system.
4. Execute command

   DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
5. Execute command

   minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv