# Unable to start minikube and exiting due to PROVIDER_HYPERV_NOT_FOUND

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, hyper-v, hypervisor

We are getting the below error while running the command "minikube start --driver=hyperv" which was initially working properly but suddenly started giving an error.

C:\Windows\system32>minikube start --driver=hyperv

- minikube v1.22.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.19043 Build 19043
- Using the hyperv driver based on user configuration
- Exiting due to PROVIDER_HYPERV_NOT_FOUND: The 'hyperv' provider was not found: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive @(Get-Wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem).HypervisorPresent returned "False\r\n"
- Suggestion: Enable Hyper-V: Start PowerShell as Administrator, and run: 'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All'
- Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/hyperv/

We tried to disabled and enabled the "hyperv" from the Windows Features tab and then restarted the machine but it didn't work.

When we hit a command "systeminfo" we got the below, saying "hyperv" is enabled.

Hyper-V Requirements:
VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes

```
                  Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes

                  Second Level Address Translation: Yes

                  Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

Now we have enabled the "hyperv", restarted the machine but still we are getting the error, could anyone please help us out in this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Welcome to the community! Similar issue was asked and resolved in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60447586/hyperv-does-not-appear-to-be-installed). Please try it and let us know if this helps

Comment: Your minikube cluster is already started thats why it is giving this error. It was the case in mine. Try running minikube status to check the same

Answer (score 0):

Reason:  missing powershell.exe path

Resolution:  Add C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 into Environmental Variables... > System variables > Path

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did - I'm not sure which part fixed it

- `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`
- Followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855801/270155)
- `powershell -version 5`
- `minikube start --vm-driver hyperv ...`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this page Hopefully it will fix your problem. we need to install dependencies first.
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/
[image]
https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c

if you are using docker desktop then switch to linux containers and the run **minikube start**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me worked to switch to powershall 7 instead of cmd/powershall
and run the commands there